# Why aren't included modules showing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my config/initializers/[refinery](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms) folder, there are some config files structured as

```
initializers
 ├── backtrace_silencers.rb
 ├── inflections.rb
 ├── mime_types.rb 
 ├── refinery
 │   ├── authentication.rb
 │   ├── core.rb
 │   ├── i18n.rb
 │   ├── images.rb
 │   ├── page_images.rb
 │   ├── pages.rb
 │   └── resources.rb
 ├── secret_token.rb
 ├── session_store.rb
 └── wrap_parameters.rb
```

With `refinery/` with `rails console --sandbox`, I get

```
  Refinery.included_modules
  #=> []
```

Why? When I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `Refinery::P`, it shows the following modules.

```
Refinery::Page                 Refinery::PagePart             Refinery::PaginationHelper     
Refinery::PageImages           Refinery::Pages                Refinery::Plugin               
Refinery::PageImagesGenerator  Refinery::PagesGenerator       Refinery::Plugins
```

If it has `::`, it must be somewhere and has to include it. Then why is `include_modules` working? Please correct me if I am wrong and show me the correct approach to display the modules or classes which are inside the  modules. I referred http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those modules aren't "included" in `Refinery`, which is why they are not listed in `included_modules`.

"Including" has a specific meaning in Ruby -- basically, it's when a class or module "mixes in" another module -- whereas something like `Refinery::Page` is *namespacing*. Check out the [Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html), which explains it well.

Try `Refinery.constants` to get what you are after.